# IOS equivalent of sha fingerprints

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, sha

I was going to add a SHA fingerprint using firebase to my flutter app. I noticed there wasn't an option in firebase for a fingerprint on the IOS app like there is in the android settings and was wondering what the equivalent is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The app ID is the equivalent, on iOS you have Bundle ID and App ID, where on Android you only have a Bundle ID.

Comment: do I not need to do anything on firebase with the IOS settings then?

Comment: Yes you need to add the GoogleService-Info.plist in your file tree after adding the Bundle App ID and the App ID on Firebase Console.

Comment: I am not sure we are talking about the same thing. I mean an Ios equivalent to this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth